# Question about integration by calculating residues

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate the following integral around the contour $|z|=3$  $$\int_c z^{2}e^{\frac{1}{z}}$$ by using residues

Approach: So we have to use power series expansion in the form $a_n(z)^n$ because the singularity is at $z=0$

$z^2e^{\frac{1}{z}}=z^2(1+(1/z)+(1/z)^2+(1/z)^3)$. Clearly the coefficient at $1/z$ is 1, so the value of the integral would $2\pi i$, but the answer is $\pi i /3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't expanded $z^2 e^{1/z}$ correctly. It should be

$$z^2 e^{\frac{1}{z}}  = z^2\left(1 + \frac{1}{z} + \color{red}{\frac{1}{2!}}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^2 + \color{red}{\frac{1}{3!}}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^3 + \cdots\right)$$

The coefficient of $1/z$ in this expansion is $1/3!$. Hence, the answer is $2\pi i(1/3!) = \pi i/3$.